# Writing the dyadic product of two vectors as some product of a matrix and a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

For a physics problem I have a vector $\mathbf{v}$ which is defined as $$\mathbf{v}=\mathrm{M}\mathbf{u},$$ with $\mathrm{M}$ a matrix and $\mathbf{u}$ a second vector. I am interested in the second-order components of $\mathbf{v}$ ($v_1^2,v_1v_2$ and $v_2^2$) which are conveniently generated by taking the dyadic product $\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{v}$. Now my question is whether it is possible to write this dyadic product $\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{v}$ as the seperated product of $\mathrm{M}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ $$\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{v}=g(\mathrm{M})f(\mathbf{u}),$$
with $f$ and $g$ some function.  I have been trying to work this out by inspecting some algebra properties and taking the tensor product explicitly and seeing if I can work out the pattern, but no luck so far. An erroneous example would be $\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{v}\neq\mathrm{M}\cdot(\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{u})$, which does yield a two-tensor but with the wrong values. My motivation for this construction stems from the physical significance of $\mathrm{M}$ and $\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: In index notation/summation convention, $v\otimes v=v_i v_j$, while $v_i=M_{ia}u_a$ and so $v_i v_j=(M_{ia} M_{jb}) (u_a u_b) $. This is a contraction between a fourth-order tensor formed from $M$, and a second-order tensor $u\otimes u$ formed from $u$. I am not sure how this would be expressed in dyadic notation - can you take a dyadic product of matrices? Would the kroenecker product work?

Comment: I didn't think of the possibility that dyadic notation does not make sense for matrices and index notation may be more natural. The fact that the fourth-order tensor and second-order tensor have different lengths might be a clue that index notation should be used, as dot products don't make sense for tensors with different lengths. Thanks!

Comment: $$(v\otimes v)^{ij}=v^iv^j=(M^i{}_k u^k)(M^j{}_lu^l)  =(M\otimes M)^{ij}{}_{kl}(u\otimes u)^{kl}$$
Don't think you can do much better than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v \otimes v$ is $(M \otimes M)(u \otimes u)$, as K.defaoite says in the comments. This follows from what is called the [exchange law](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exchange+law) or interchange law relating Kronecker product and matrix multiplication. More generally we have

$$(X_1 \otimes X_2)(Y_1 \otimes Y_2) = X_1 Y_1 \otimes X_2 Y_2$$

where $X_i, Y_i$ are such that the matrix multiplications above make sense.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to specify the indices as per K.defaoite's comment? Or does the order of operations uniquely define the contractions between $X_1\otimes X_2$ and $Y_1\otimes Y_2$? There seem to be 12 separate ways a tensor of rank 4 and 2 can contract, but I guess the matrix multiplication $X_iY_i$ implicitly rules out 8 of these possible contractions?

Comment: There is a unique choice of contraction such that both sides of the interchange law make sense with the weakest possible hypotheses and I'm taking that choice. It's easiest to state in terms of linear map rather than matrices: take $X_i : V_i \to W_i$ to be linear maps and $Y_i : U_i \to V_i$ to be linear maps. So there are six different vector spaces appearing now, which is what disambiguates the intended operations. Your example is confusing because several of these linear maps and vector spaces happen to be identical; things get clearer once you generalize away from this case.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up my confusion!